# python rumps not working on OS X 10.10 - AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'App'

Tags: python, macos, user-interface, osx-yosemite

I am trying to run some demo from http://rumps.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html
using Ridiculously Uncomplicated Mac os x Python Statusbar apps and while importing rumps i get: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'App'`

```
Mac-28cfe915100b-2:Desktop andi$ pip install rumps
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): rumps in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyobjc-core in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC (from rumps)
Cleaning up...
Mac-28cfe915100b-2:Desktop andi$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import rumps
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "rumps.py", line 4, in <module>
    class AwesomeStatusBarApp(rumps.App):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'App'
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with `rumps` but rather that you copied the demo into a a file named "rumps.py". The same error will happen in any other module you are trying to import from a file named the same thing.

```
$ echo "import math; math.sqrt(42)" > math.py
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import math
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "math.py", line 1, in <module>
    import math; math.sqrt(42)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sqrt'
```